# How to post nested JSON to HTTParty in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am trying to work out the correct way to post a nested JSON object to an API using HTTParty.

I am getting a successful response using Postman to test the call:

POST: `http://service.net/api`

Headers: `x-api-key : apikey123`

Body :

```
{
    "VehicleRequests": [{
        "Id": "Vehicle1",
        "Parameters": {
            "Term": 60,
            "CashDeposit": 10,
            "DepositType": "Percentage",
            "AnnualMileage": 10000
        },
        "PhysicalVehicle": {
            "ExternalVehicleId": "12345",
            "Type": "Car",
            "Status": "PreOwned",
            "OnTheRoadPrice": "30000",
            "Mileage": "12345",
            "Registration": {
                "RegistrationNumber": "REGN0",
                "DateRegisteredWithDvla": "01/01/2018"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

This returns:

```
{
  "Vehicles": [
    {
      "Id": "Vehicle1",
      "HasError": false,
      "Error": null,
      "FinanceQuotations": [
        {
          "HasError": false,
          "Error": null,
          "Finance": {
            "Key": "HP",
            "Notifications": [],
            "Quote": {
             .....
            }
          }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

But i'm struggling to replicate the call from my rails app. I have a class set up which i'm calling on create

```
class Monthlyprice
   def initialize()

        @response = HTTParty.post('http://service.net/api',  
        :body =>{
            :VehicleRequests=> [{
                :Id => "Vehicle1",
                :Parameters => {
                    :Term => 60,
                    :CashDeposit => 10,
                    :DepositType => "Percentage",
                    :AnnualMileage => 10000
                },
                :PhysicalVehicle => {
                    :ExternalVehicleId => "12345",
                    :Type => "Car",
                    :Status => "PreOwned",
                    :OnTheRoadPrice => "30000",
                    :Mileage => "12345",
                    :Registration => {
                        :RegistrationNumber => "REGN0",
                        :DateRegisteredWithDvla => "01/01/2018"
                    }
                }
            }].to_json
        },
        :headers => {"x-api-key" => "apikey123"})

        puts(@response)
    end
end
```

But this is returning the following error message from the API:

```
{"Error"=>{"UserMessage"=>"Request is invalid.", "TechnicalMessage"=>"Request Validation failed. Request had 2 error(s). 1: request.VehicleRequests[0].Id - The Id field is required.\r\n2: request.VehicleRequests[0].Parameters - The Parameters field is required.", "Code"=>"80000"}}
```

This is the same error that I get from the api in postman if I remove the Id and Parameters objects which suggests the contents of my VehicleRequests object is formatted incorrectly? Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the syntax like below :-

```
:body => {
         }.to_json
```

that means you have to use `.to_json` where the body parenthesis close I think it's only syntax error.

**Syntax** :-

```
response = HTTParty.post("your request URL",
                  headers: {
                    .....
                    #your header content
                    .....
                  },
                  body: {
                  ......
                   #your body content
                  .....

                   }.to_json
                 )
```

I have just edited in your code please try below code :-

```
@response = HTTParty.post('http://service.net/api',
        :headers => {"x-api-key" => "apikey123"},  
        :body =>{
            :VehicleRequests=> [{
                :Id => "Vehicle1",
                :Parameters => {
                    :Term => 60,
                    :CashDeposit => 10,
                    :DepositType => "Percentage",
                    :AnnualMileage => 10000
                },
                :PhysicalVehicle => {
                    :ExternalVehicleId => "12345",
                    :Type => "Car",
                    :Status => "PreOwned",
                    :OnTheRoadPrice => "30000",
                    :Mileage => "12345",
                    :Registration => {
                        :RegistrationNumber => "REGN0",
                        :DateRegisteredWithDvla => "01/01/2018"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }.to_json
        )
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Unfortunately It hasn't solved the issue though. the Error message now says 
```{"Error"=>{"UserMessage"=>"Request is invalid.", "TechnicalMessage"=>"No VehicleRequests supplied ", "Code"=>"80000"}}```
Any ideas?

Comment: In above you have done a syntax error which I have corrected but I don't know about your api's that you are using or for which purpose.